# Не могу сделать спиннер в Boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4, bootstrap5

Проверьте пожалуйста в чём ошибка

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуй добавить в пути `./`  src="./script.js" href="./style.css"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

подключи хорошенько bootstrap и будет работать
свои скрипты замени на мои и css